# To delete DNS records in AD-integrated DNS, what permissions are needed and where?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, windows-dns

I would like to be able to allow a specific user to delete DNS records from my Active Directory-integrated DNS zones.

One zone is replicated to all DNS servers on DCs in the domain (so in DomainDnsZones).

Another zone is replicated to all domain controllers in the domain (so in CN=System,CN=MicrosoftDNS,DC= in the domain).

The reverse lookup zones are replicated to all DNS servers in the forests (so in ForestDNSZones).

I've tried adding `Delete` on `All descendant objects` to the zone in DomainDnsZones and the appropriate reverse lookup zone in ForestDNSZones.  For example, using `Get-Acl` on the DomainDnsZone shows (for the specified account):

```
ActiveDirectoryRights : Delete
AccessControlType     : Allow
InheritanceFlags      : ContainerInherit
PropagationFlags      : InheritOnly
InheritanceType       : Descendents
```

but I get ACCESS DENIED when I try to delete a sample record using `DNSCMD`.

Why isn't this sifficient?  What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's amazing that this information is so difficult to find. I wasn't able to find a single resource that effectively explained this, but I needed to delegate the deletion of records to a service account and I wanted to do so with the least privilege. After much trial and error, I came up with this, applied to the zone itself (this fit my needs, you may need to bring it up a level in ADSI Edit):

`Delete` and `Write all properties`
Applied to: `All descendant objects`

You likely need `Read` if it isn't already granted through some other membership.

I specifically *did not* need `Delete all child objects` on the parent; this seemed to do nothing.